# C# AIM Bot Not Loading Libraries from AOL SDK

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, gac

I am trying to get an AIM Bot set up in C# and I am having issues with the Assemblies.  I have tried placing the DLL files in the BIN folder of the project and in the windows/system32 folders.  I have registered the DLL files so that I could add them to the project in VS2008.  I also attempted the install them into the GAC but I keed getting errors.  Digging further I do not seem to have the GAS and SN utilities installed in the locations most users do.

How can I get the utilities I need to install these libraries in their correct location and do I actually need to install these libraries this way?  Or am I completely on the wrong page and have to do something else.

The error I am getting from my debug of the project is:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
>   Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned
>   from a call to a COM component. at
>   AccCoreLib.IAccSession.set_Identity(String
>   pIdentity)

any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't sound like an issue with loading the libraries at all.  Based on the error message the libraries have loaded just fine and you are able to successfully create a COM object from them.  The call to the object in the library though is failing with E_FAIL.

I'm not familiar with this library but DLL location doesn't appear to be the issue.  It appears to be a problem in the way in which the API is being used.

Comment: Interesting.  I tried running a sample that was provided by the open AIM development.  I will double check my syntax to make sure that is not the issue.